# How to Install vuetify in laravel 9 starter kits?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to install Vuetify in my Laravel 9 project. I am using the Breeze Vue starter kit. Any idea how to install it?

Do I need to install it directly in the project, or what is the way to make the configuration?????

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution you can do it in this way:

first install vuetify

```
npm install vuetify
```

Inside resources/js, create vuetify.js file (resources/js/vuetify.js)and populate it with Vuetify configuration and theming options, like this:

```
import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

const customeTheme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: "#673AB7",
        secondary: "#424242",
        accent: "#82B1FF",
        error: "#FF5252",
        info: "#2196F3",
        success: "#4CAF50",
        warning: "#FFC107",
        lightblue: "#14c6FF",
        yellow: "#FFCF00",
        pink: "#FF1976",
        orange: "#FF8657",
        magenta: "#C33AFC",
        darkblue: "#1E2D56",
        gray: "#909090",
        neutralgray: "#9BA6C1",
        green: "#2ED47A",
        red: "#FF5c4E",
        darkblueshade: "#308DC2",
        lightgray: "#BDBDBD",
        lightpink: "#FFCFE3",
        white: "#FFFFFF",
        muted: "#6c757d",
    },
};

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: "customeTheme",
        themes: {
            customeTheme,
        },
    },
});
```

export default vuetify;

then in app.js use this:

```
    import './bootstrap';
    import '../css/app.css';

    import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
    import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
    import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia- 
    helpers';
    import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
    import vuetify from "./vuetify";

    const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title'). 
    [0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

  createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(vuetify)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

This is for starter kits breeze vue laravel 9

I hope it help you